# Parameter binding of POST action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

You can see what **GET Delete** action method passes DDW2File object to view. Is it possible somehow to bind this object back to **ddw2file** parameter of **POST Delete** action method? Now I have **null** value in it.

Code fragment:

```
public class DDW2FileController : Controller
{
    ...

    public ActionResult Delete(string fileName)
    {
        return View(repository.GetFile(fileName));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Delete(DDW2File ddw2file)
    {
        repository.Delete(file);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

...

public class DDW2File
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Length { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this inside a form in the view should work assuming your parameter name is ddw2file as per your signature there.

```
<%=Html.TextBox("ddw2file.Name")%>
<%=Html.TextBox("ddw2file.Length")%>
```